# What are the uses of the fail predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I can't come up with a situation where I would need it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Elegant systems provide `false/0` as a declarative synonym for the imperative `fail/0`. An example where it is useful is when you manually want to force backtracking for side-effects, like:

```
?- between(1,3,N), format("line ~w\n", [N]), false.
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Instead of `false/0`, you can also use any goal that fails, for example a bit shorter:

```
?- between(1,3,N), format("line ~w\n", [N]), 0=1.
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Thus, `false/0` is not strictly needed but quite nice.

**EDIT**: I sometimes see beginners who want to state for example "my relation does not hold for the empty list", and then add:

`my_relation([]) :- false.`

to their code. This is *not* necessary, and *not* a good example of using `false/0`, except for example in failure slices that are programmatically generated. Instead, concentrate on stating the things that *hold* about your relation. In this case, just leave out the entire clause, and define the relation only for lists that are not empty, i.e., have at least one element:

`my_relation([L|Ls]) :- etc.`

or, if you are describing other terms in addition to lists as well, use a constraint like:

`my_relation(T) :- dif(T, []), etc.`

Given only either (or even both) of these two clauses, the query `?- my_relation([]).` will automatically fail. It is not necessary to introduce an additional clause which never succeeds for that purpose.

Comment: s/elegant/elegant and conforming/

Answer (score 10):

**Explicit failure.** `fail` is often used in conjunction with cut: `... !, fail.` to enforce failure.

**For all construct.** Explicit usage of `fail`/`false` to enumerate *via* backtracking is a very error prone activity. Consider a case:

```
... ( generator(X), action(X), fail ; true ), ...
```

The idea is thus to "do" action for all `X`. But what happens, if `action(X)` fails? This construct simply continues with the next candidate — as if nothing happened. In this manner certain errors may remain undetected for very long.

For such cases it is better to use `\+ ( generator(X), \+ action(X) )` which fails, should `action(X)` fail for some `X`. Some systems offer this as a built-in `forall/2`. Personally, I prefer to use `\+` in this case because the `\+` is a bit clearer that the construct does not leave a binding.

**Failure-slice.** For diagnostic purposes it is often useful to add on purpose `false` into your programs. See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

One case (taken from [Constraint Logic Programming using Eclipse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521866286)) is an implementation of not/1:

```
:- op(900, fy, not).
not Q :- Q, !, fail.
not _ .
```

If Q succeeds, the cut (!) causes the second not clause to be discarded, and the fail ensures a negative result. If Q fails, then the second not clause fires first.

Answer (score 3):

Another use for fail is to force backtracking through alternatives when using predicates with side effects:

```
writeall(X) :- member(A,X), write(A), fail.
writeall(_).
```

Some people might not consider this particularly good programming style though. :)

Comment: Oops, looks like mat beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

fail/0 is a special symbol that will immediately fail when prolog encounters it as a goal.

fail is often used in conjunction with CUT(!) to enforce failure.

```
like(me,X) :- chess(X),!,fail.
like(me,X) :- games(X).
```