# How to force a fail in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

In prolog, is it possible to force a fail? Something like:

```
check(F,A,[1,2,3]) :- FAIL.
check(F,A,_) : greater_than(F,A).
```

This may be a bad example, but something along the lines of this.

So if it does a pattern match on F,A,[1,2,3], then we just stop the who unifying process, and return a false.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001825/what-are-the-uses-of-the-fail-predicate-in-prolog?rq=1, esp. the last answer

Comment: maybe `check(_,_,[1,2,3]) :- !, fail.`

Answer (score 1):

Prolog has a built-in [`fail/0`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=fail/0) predicate, which always fails. You need a cut `!` in front of it in order to prevent further matching of the same `check/3` rule:

```
check(F,A,[1,2,3]) :- !, fail.
```