# PROLOG result vs true

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have the next code in a file called "testing.pl":

```
fact(1).
fact(2).
fact(3).

funcA(X) :- funcB(X).

funcB(X) :- fact(X).

testing :- funcA(_X).
```

Then, in SWI-Prolog interpreter I query `funcA(X).` and the output is:

```
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

But, whenever I query `testing.` the output is:

```
true ;
true ;
true.
```

So, my questions is:

How can I use the conclusion of a rule as a premise of another rule (`funcA(X)` at the right of `testing`), but having the same effect as if I query that premise (`funcA(X)`)?

In the example above, I would like to write `testing.` at some point of my "testing.pl" file and to get the funcA(X) to do the same like when I query with the interpreter, so funcB(X) will check for all values that X can take from fact(N) and return it.

My desire result would be to write `testing.` and to get on screen:

```
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want `testing.` to result in `X = 1, ...` then you need to have `X` be an argument to `testing`. So, `testing(X) :- funcA(X).` (which doesn't seem to add any purpose). Alternatively, and less preferably, you could write the results: `testing :- funcA(X), write('X = '), write(X), nl.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *manually* print anything on the terminal, using for example predicates like `portray_clause/1`, `format/2` etc.

The only additional piece you need is a way to **force backtracking** over all answers. One way to do it is [using `false/0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001941/1613573).

So, in your case, you can write for example:

```
testing :-
        funcA(X),
        format("X = ~q ;~n", [X]),
        false.
```

And now invoking `testing/0` yields, *without any further interaction*:

```
?- testing.
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
```

In addition, the predicates now **fails**, so you also get `false/0` if you use it interactively (from the toplevel), but *not* if you invoke `testing` from the shell via `swipl -g testing ...`.

Also take a look at the important `variable_names/1` option that is available to use the intended variable names.

I lave tailoring this output to your exact use case as an exercise. Ideally, the output should be a proper **Prolog term**, so that you can actually *test* it easily by reading it with `read/1` and comparing it to a reference result.

Comment: Really nice answer, but the problem I presented was just an abstraction of my real code, which unfortunately is interactive (is in a menu loop). So it gets stuck at the false. Anyway, is the answer to what I asked, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me also address your actual code: One clean way out is to first *separate* the impurities (i.e., input/output) from the actual program logic. For example, to represent a menu in a **pure** way, use a predicate like `menu0_key_menu/3`, *relating* one state of the menu to a new state of the menu, depending on which `Key` is pressed. This way, you can actually *test* how your menu behaves by reasoning about this pure relation, "simulating" the actual key presses by simply providing them in goals, like `menu0_key_menu(M0, q, exit).`, which should *succeed* (for example).