# How to force a result to be false in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to know if it is possible to force a result e.g.

```
test(0, 0, 0).
```

to be false in Prolog.

Comment: Well usually you do this by writing the logic of `test/3` that way.

Comment: [See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001825/335858)

Comment: You could write `test(0,0,0) :- fail.`. But, the most appropriate way to ensure a query fails is to not present facts and rules that enable it to succeed. Forcing failure could be a bad code smell.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with a little helper predicate like so:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

test_(X,Y,Z) :-                        % base relation
   Z #= X+Y.                           % here: integer sum

test(X,Y,Z) :-                         % exclude (0,0,0) as a solution
   abs(X) + abs(X-Y) + abs(Y-Z) #\= 0,
   test_(X,Y,Z).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- test(1,1,2).
true
?- test(1,-1,0).
true
```

Note how the unwanted solution is excluded:

```
?- test_(0,0,0).            % 0+0 = 0
true
?- test(0,0,0).
false
```