# Problem with simple recursion task in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm currently solving some problems in prolog and I can't seem to get it work with one question regarding recursion, I have been presented with this table: [Gryffindor Table](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/courses/esslli04prolog/contents/gryffindor_table.gif).

Given that information, I made my own KB with this content:

```
/*
 This order represents how they are sit from left to right
 parvati_patil is left to lavender_brown,
 lavender_brown is left to neville_longbottom
 and so on, until we reach parvati again at the end.
*/

seatedTogether(parvati_patil, lavender_brown).
seatedTogether(lavender_brown, neville_longbottom).
seatedTogether(neville_longbottom, alicia_spinnet).
seatedTogether(alicia_spinnet, fred_weasley).
seatedTogether(fred_weasley, george_weasley).
seatedTogether(george_weasley, lee_jordan).
seatedTogether(lee_jordan, dennis_creevey).
seatedTogether(dennis_creevey, dean_thomas).
seatedTogether(dean_thomas, ginny_weasley).
seatedTogether(ginny_weasley, angelina_johnson).
seatedTogether(angelina_johnson, seamus_finnigan).
seatedTogether(seamus_finnigan, colin_creevey).
seatedTogether(colin_creevey, harry_potter).
seatedTogether(harry_potter, hermione_granger).
seatedTogether(hermione_granger, ron_weasley).
seatedTogether(ron_weasley, natalie_mcdonald).
seatedTogether(natalie_mcdonald, katie_bell).
seatedTogether(katie_bell, parvati_patil).

% X is left to Y if they are seatedTogether(X,Y)
isAtLeft(X,Y):-seatedTogether(X,Y).
% X is right to Y if they are seatedTogether(Y,X)
isAtRight(X,Y):-seatedTogether(Y,X).

/*
 This rule just tells us who X is two places away from Y,
 X is two places away from Y if 
 X is seatedTogether(X,Z)
 and that Z is seatedTogether(Z,Y).
*/
twoPlacesAway(X,Y):-seatedTogether(X, Z), seatedTogether(Z,Y).

/*
  This rule just tells us whos sitting @ the table
  by just unifying X with the values of seatedTogether(X,Y)
  without regarding Y.
*/
atTable(X):-seatedTogether(X,_).


/*
  Between two:
  Its supposed to tell us whos Z is between X and Y
  The perfect case (for me) would be that X and Y are sitting
  together, so they have no one in the middle.
  The other way around would be that
  X is not equal to Y
  X1 is sitting left to X,
  and then we call it again with
  X1, Y and Z1 as args,
  after each call, we equal
  Z to X1 value.
*/
betweenTwo(X,Y,Z):-isAtLeft(X,Y),isAtRight(Y,X).
betweenTwo(X,Y,Z):-
    X \= Y,
    isAtLeft(X, X1),
    betweenTwo(X1, Y, Z1),
    Z = X1.
```

The problem comes with the last rule definition, if I call it like this:

```
betweenTwo(ron_weasley, alicia_spinnet, Z).
```

The value of Z should be:

- natalie_mcdonald,
- katie_bell,
- parvati_patil,
- lavender_brown,
- neville_longbottom.

But Z only unifies with the value of

- natalie_mcdonald.

I believe I'm super close to it, but I'm really lost on what's going wrong  with that rule. I defined it so X step by step equals the value of Y, but with the value before Y it should fall in the perfect case and stop moving, and unify the rest of elements before it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First: your base case (what you call "perfect case") says "if `X` is at left of `Y`, and `Y` is at right of `X`, then every `Z` is between them", instead of "no one is between them" (the conditions are redundant as well). The base case should say when the predicate holds (that is, when some `Z` is between `X` and `Y`), not when it doesn't. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001941/9204

Second: in the non-base case, you have

```
isAtLeft(X, X1),
betweenTwo(X1, Y, Z1),
Z = X1.
```

When Prolog searches for `X1` in `isAtLeft(ron_weasley, X1)`, the only answer is `natalie_mcdonald`, and later `Z = X1` forces `Z` to be `natalie_mcdonald` too.

So this part of your code is equivalent to

```
isAtLeft(X, Z),
betweenTwo(Z, Y, Z1).
```

or in words "`Z` is between `X` and `Y` if: `X` is not equal to `Y`, `X` is directly to the left of `Z`, and some `Z1` is between `Z` and `Y`", which doesn't make sense.

You should note the warning about singleton variable `Z1`, too.

Comment: Following your corrections I made my own checkings, changing the base case to this: `betweenTwo(X,Y,Z):-isAtLeft(X, Z),isAtLeft(Z, Y).` and the non-base case to this: `betweenTwo(X,Y,Z):-
    X \= Y,
    isAtLeft(X, Z),
    betweenTwo(Z, Y, Z1).` And I still got only `natalie_mcdonald.`I checked the answer you sent and I really didn't get it quite right...

Comment: This fixes the base base, but in the non-base case my point was not that you should change to this, but that your code already works like this and you should see why it means it's wrong. Hint: `isAtLeft(X, Z)` (or `isAtLeft(X, X1), Z=X1`) already means you can't get any `Z` other than `natalie_mcdonald`, adding conditions could only make this answer invalid as well.

Comment: I've edited the answer, since it should be easier to read than in the comment.